# Rudimentary OOP in C

Tags: c

Experimenting with primitive OOP ideas in C.

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "reptile.h"

int main()
{
    const char *name = "Spot";
    turtle_t *t = maketurtle(name);
    t->hide(t); // <---- "Error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

    return 0;
}
```

**reptile.h:**

```
#ifndef REPTILE_H
#define REPTILE_H

typedef struct turtle_t turtle_t;
turtle_t* maketurtle(const char *name);
void hide(turtle_t *self);

#endif // REPTILE_H
```

**reptile.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "reptile.h"

typedef struct turtle_t
{
    int numoflegs;
    const char name[25];
    void (*hide)(turtle_t *self);

} turtle_t;

turtle_t* maketurtle(const char *name)
{
    turtle_t *t = (turtle_t*)malloc(sizeof(turtle_t));
    t->name = name;
    return t;
}

void hide(turtle_t *self)
{
    printf("The turtle %s has withdrawn into his shell!", self->name);
}
```

Is there something I am missing? I have looked at a similar case here on stack overflow and my code looks identical at least in structure, so I am a bit confused. Thanks in advance!

p.s. if this is a linker error how do I get it to compile in an IDE without throwing an error?

Comment: Side note, consider prefixing your method names with the type they belong to to avoid potential naming conflicts.

Comment: Another side note: you should make a hard copy of the `name` variable, not just let a pointer point to the string literal. That is, replace `t->name = name;` with strcpy.

Comment: A third side note: Consider making your functions `static`. Even if you use your structures with pointers to functions, the actual functions themselves can still be `static`. This avoids name-clashes when you link with other files that might contain exported functions with the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the compiler works on the `main.c` file, it knows that there is a structure named `turtle_t` but it knows nothing about it, it's not completely defined.

You need to make the structure "public", or at least the parts that are supposed to be public. This can easily be done by using *two* structures, one for the public "methods" and member variables, and another nested that contains the private data. Something like

```
typedef struct turtle_private_t turtle_private_t;
typedef struct turtle_t turtle_t;

struct turtle_t
{
    turtle_private_t *private;  // For private data
    void (*hide)(turtle_t *self);
};
```

As an alternative, and one that is common, is that you don't place public functions in the structure, but instead use normal functions, with a special prefix to their name to indicate class. Something like

```
turtle_t *turtle_create(void);  // Creates the turtle
void turtle_hide(turtle_t *);   // Hides the turtle
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Which approach is more widely used?

Comment: It is usually a much better idea not to make the struct public, but to use incomplete type the hide the struct declaration to the caller.

Comment: @Rhurac The latter is probably more common, but it depends quite a lot on personal preference, company rules or requirements, and environment. A common example of the latter way, with stand-alone public functions with a prefix is the standard I/O function using the opaque `FILE` structure.

Answer (score 4):

You need to move your

```
typedef struct turtle_t
{
    int numoflegs;
    const char name[25];
    void (*hide)(turtle_t *self);

} turtle_t;
```

from the .c file to the .h file. Incomplete type means, that the type is not known at compile type (it will be only known at link-time, if it's contained in a different translation unit). That means in your main.c `turtle_t` is only forward-declared and the structure itself is unknown - moving it to your .h file shall do the trick.